# Why is this Xpath not working with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to input an email address to test logging in, but I'm continuing to receive this error: `no such element: Unable to locate element:`

I have tried using the relative and absolute `Xpath` and receive the same error message.

Forgive me as I'm sure missing something simple, very new to this!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://soundcloud.com/signin'

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign_in_up_email"]').send_keys('test@test.com')
```

Comment: why not to use find element by id. driver.find_element_by_id(
            "sign_in_up_email").send_keys('test@test.com')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its throwing error is because the element `sign_in_up_email` is present inside the iframe
[Refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x85n.png)

Check the link [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-handle-frames-in-selenium-with-python) for detail about how to switch to iframe

You will first need to switch to iframe and then enter value  in the input

Note:-  When you first open the page you might see the `accept cookies` popup from soundcloud you will have to accept that

Your solution would look like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://soundcloud.com/signin'

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
# Accept cookie
driver.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
# Switch to frame
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("webAuthContainer__iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign_in_up_email"]').send_keys('test@test.com')
```

Comment: Hi @johns7843 can you try the above solution

Comment: My apologizes for the delay.  You're brilliant!

Comment: Hi @Johns7843 glad it helped can you mark the answer as approved